# Multiprocessing In Django Function

Tags: python, django, loops, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

Is it possible to use multi processing in Django on a request.

#so if I send a request to http://127.0.0.1:8000/wallet_verify

```
def wallet_verify(request):
    walelts = botactive.objects.all()
```

#here I check if the user want to be included in the process or not so if they set it to True then i'll include them else ignore.

```
    for active in walelts:
        check_active = active.active
        if check_active == True:
            user_is_active = active.user
```

#for the ones that want to be included I then go to get their key data.
I need to get both api and secret so then I loop through to get the data from active users.

```
            database = Bybitapidatas.objects.filter(user=user_is_active)
            for apikey in database:
                apikey = apikey.apikey
            for apisecret in database:
                apisecret = apisecret.apisecret
```

#since I am making a request to an exchange endpoint I can only include one API and secret at a time . So for 1 person at a time this is why I want to run in parallel.

```
            for a, b in zip(list(Bybitapidatas.objects.filter(user=user_is_active).values("apikey")), list(Bybitapidatas.objects.filter(user=user_is_active).values("apisecret"))):
                session =spot.HTTP(endpoint='https://api-testnet.bybit.com/', api_key=a['apikey'], api_secret=b['apisecret'])
```

#here I check to see if they have balance to open trades if they have selected to be included.

```
                GET_USDT_BALANCE = session.get_wallet_balance()['result']['balances']
                for i in GET_USDT_BALANCE:
                    if 'USDT' in i.values():
                        GET_USDT_BALANCE = session.get_wallet_balance()['result']['balances']
                        idx_USDT = GET_USDT_BALANCE.index(i)
                        GET_USDTBALANCE = session.get_wallet_balance()['result']['balances'][idx_USDT]['free']
                        print(round(float(GET_USDTBALANCE),2))
```

#if they don't have enough balance I skip the user.

```
                if round(float(GET_USDTBALANCE),2) < 11 :
                    pass 
                else:
                
                    session.place_active_order(
                        symbol="BTCUSDT",
                        side="Buy",
                        type="MARKET",
                        qty=10,
                        timeInForce="GTC"
                    )
```

How can I run this process in parallel while looping through the database to also get data for each individual user.

I am still new to coding so hope I explained that it makes sense.

I have tried multiprocessing and pools but then I get that the app has not started yet and I have to run it outside of wallet_verify is there a way to do it in wallet_verify

and when I send the Post Request.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to run a Django ORM request in parallel (this is very hard) or trying to run an external HTTP request in parallel (this is very easy) ?

Comment: If I send a request to http://127..../verify_wallet then everything runs smoothly but it takes a long time since it run individually . so it take a few seconds per user . I want to run the entire section from ```      for a, b in zip ...``` in a parallel loop when I send request

Answer (score 0):

Filtering the Database to get Users who have set it to True
Listi - [1,3](these are user ID's Returned

```
processess = botactive.objects.filter(active=True).values_list('user')
listi = [row[0] for row in processess]
```

Get the Users from the listi and perform the action.

```
def wallet_verify(listi):
    # print(listi)
    database = Bybitapidatas.objects.filter(user = listi)
    print("---------------------------------------------------- START")
    for apikey in database:
        apikey = apikey.apikey
        print(apikey)
    for apisecret in database:
        apisecret = apisecret.apisecret
        print(apisecret)
        start_time = time.time()

        session =spot.HTTP(endpoint='https://api-testnet.bybit.com/', api_key=apikey, api_secret=apisecret)

    GET_USDT_BALANCE = session.get_wallet_balance()['result']['balances']
    for i in GET_USDT_BALANCE:
        if 'USDT' in i.values():
            GET_USDT_BALANCE = session.get_wallet_balance()['result']['balances']
            idx_USDT = GET_USDT_BALANCE.index(i)
            GET_USDTBALANCE = session.get_wallet_balance()['result']['balances'][idx_USDT]['free']
            print(round(float(GET_USDTBALANCE),2))

    if round(float(GET_USDTBALANCE),2) < 11 :
        pass 
    else:
    
        session.place_active_order(
            symbol="BTCUSDT",
            side="Buy",
            type="MARKET",
            qty=10,
            timeInForce="GTC"
        )
    print ("My program took", time.time() - start_time, "to run")
    print("---------------------------------------------------- END")
    return HttpResponse("Wallets verified")
```

Verifyt is what I use for the multiprocessing since I don't want it to run without being requested to run. also initialiser starts apps for each loop

````
def verifyt(request):
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4, initializer=django.setup) as executor:
        results = executor.map(wallet_verify, listi)
    return HttpResponse("done")
    ```
````